# How to make the row to column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have some problem to convert row to column. The Original table is like this

```
  Date     CD      C1      C2    Amount  
2019-01    FEE     Y       N       100
2019-01    FEE     Y       Y       200
2019-01    REV     Y       N       300
2019-02    FEE     Y       N       100
2019-02    REV     N       N       100
```

I want to get the following table

```
 Date     C1    C2   FEE      REV     Total
2019-01   Y     N    100      300      400
2019-01   Y     Y    200      null     200
2019-02   Y     N    100      null     100
2019-02   N     N    null     100      100
```

I tried to use the decode() function like

```
select Date, C1, C2,
       decode(cd,'FEE', Amount) FEE,
       decode(cd,'REV', Amount) REV
from table group by.........
```

It will get the result

```
 Date     C1    C2   FEE      REV     
2019-01   Y     N    100      null
2019-01   Y     N    null     300
2019-01   Y     Y    200      null
```

I want to put the data on the same row if they have the same Date, C1 and C2.
How to write the query about that? Any help? Thanks!

Comment: If Date, C1 and C2 are part of the group by clause, you should get the output you expect.

Comment: Are FEE and REV the only possible values in column CD?

Answer (score 0):

You need aggregation.  I would recommend `case` for the conditional part:

```
select Date, C1, C2,
       sum(case when cd = 'FEE' then Amount end) as FEE,
       sum(case when cd = 'REV' then Amount end) as REV,
       sum(Amount) as TOTAL
from table
group by Date, C1, C2;
```

Comment: Records are still on different rows if they have the same date, c1 and c2

Comment: @HenlenLee . . . Then the three columns are not identical.  You might have spaces around string values or the `date` might have a time component.  This cannot produce different rows if the values are identical because of the `group by`.